# Unable to shrink the transaction log file in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Am using the below to script shrink the transaction log

*USE AVPC
GO 
 BACKUP DATABASE AVPC
    TO DISK = 'H:\DBBackup\AVPC\FullBackUp\AVPC.bak'
USE AVPC
GO 
 BACKUP LOG AVPC
    TO DISK = 'H:\DBBackup\AVPC\Transaction\AVPC.trn'
GO

USE AVPC
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE AVPC
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
checkpoint
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (AVPC_log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE AVPC
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO*

But I was not able to succeed, I didnt get any error but the log didnt shrink.I also verified for any open transactions,but there was none.
And also we do Full Back for twice a week and transaction log back up for every mins.

Can any one help me to shrink the log file.It is really growing big.

Answer (score 0):

DBCC LOGINFO will show you the active portion of your transaction log. Is the active part of the log at the end?

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on sizes of your Virtual Log Files inside of your log
If the log file was created as 16 Gb file, it has 16 VLFs of 1 Gb each inside and thus can be shrunk only to 1 Gb size, not less. And if the active VLF is the 3rd for example - it will not shrink less than 3 Gb